# Override Android background in custom style for one theme but not another

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm using two themes for my Android application, `AppTheme` and `AppThemeDark`. I've set up a custom button style for each in the theme definitions:

```
<!-- Theme definitions -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyleDark</item>
    ...
</style>

<!-- Button styles -->
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyleDark" parent="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gray_button_bg</item>
</style>
```

Note that my AppTheme button, ButtonStyle, doesn't override the background of `Widget.AppCompat.Button`, but AppThemeDark's button style inherits ButtonStyle and it changes the background.

Now, I would like to extend that buttonStyle with a new custom style for special buttons, e.g. `PrimaryButton`. In the AppTheme case, I do not want to change the background of the button. In the AppThemeDark case, i *do* want to change the background of the button.

I would like to define PrimaryButton and have it either inherit the background (in the case of AppTheme) or use a new background (AppThemeDark). Something like this:

```
<style name="PrimaryButton">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/drawablePrimaryButtonBackground</item>
</style>
```

But as far as I can tell, there's no way to define an attribute in AppThemeDark as a new drawable and AppTheme as "inherit from parent". Setting to transparent obviously makes the button background in AppTheme transparent.

Is my only option to figure out what drawable is being used for a background in Widget.AppCompat.Button and define it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question...

1. You can dig up the private Android resource and use a local copy to retain the background. That locks you into one specific Android version of the drawable though (unless you copy multiple versions over).
2. You can set whole styles as attributes if the styles between your two themes are different enough to warrant it:

**attrs.xml:**

```
<attr name="stylePrimaryButton" format="reference" />
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<!-- Theme definitions -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="stylePrimaryButton">@style/PrimaryButton</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="stylePrimaryButton">@style/PrimaryButtonDark</item>
    ...
</style>

<!-- Primary button styles -->
<style name="PrimaryButton">
    <!-- no need to override anything -->
</style>

<style name="PrimaryButtonDark">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dark_background</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml:**

```
    <Button style="?attr/stylePrimaryButton"
    ...
```